# Trying to plot y function over range, cannot make it work

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot the y function over the range `0<=x<=7` and I had been able to make something show up a while ago, but my computer crashed and I lost the work that I had on it. Needless to say I am now frazzled and frustrated.

This is what I currently have but **my graph is showing up blank now**.

Thank you for any help, I truly do appreciate it.

```
script{
  y = ((3*x^2)-(12*x)+20)/((x^2)-(7*x)+10)
  plot(x, y)
  hold
  axis([0 7 0 40])
  hold
}
```

UPDATE:
I had tried using ./ and .* for some reason they weren't in the doc I had saved my code in.
This is what I currently have:

```
x = 1:0.01:7;
y = ((3*x.^2)-(12*x)+20)/((x.^2)-(7*x)+10)

plot(x, y)
axis([0 7 0 40])
```

Comment: what is x defined to? you left a crucial line out. Also assuming your x is a vector (i.e. x=1:0.01:7) you will need x.^2 instead of x^2.

Comment: You probably want to use element-wise operations for the ²: ```y = ((3*x.^2)-(12*x)+20)./((x.^2)-(7*x)+10)```. You also need to define the step size for your vector ```x``` (I assumed it is a vector).

Comment: Please, format your code as code. You can just select it and press Ctrl+k. And indent it properly so it's readable for everybody. Thanks.

Comment: You may have use of the [Matlab Primers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf?s_tid=int_tut)

Answer (score 0):

The result of your equation is a scalar not a vector.
This is because you are using the `^` and `/` operators instead of `.^` and `./` (which perform element by element operations).

Also you don't need to call `hold` to define axis. `hold` is used if you want to plot two variables in the same plot.